# How can i put json on internet

Tags: android, json

i am an android developer (beginner).
I never developed a server or php site.
But in some project i developed android application which send and receive parameters using web services.
I want to know how can add my json file to the internet so i can obtain an  url containing this JSON file, so i can read it from my android application.
I know how to read it but i want just to know how to put it in internet so this file will have an url. And is it possible to change the json file without changing the url?

Comment: Just have a program create the json file, and put it on your webserver. You can update it whenever you want, but there is a possibility you are writing the new file when someone is trying to access it.

Answer (score 1):

first, go to this link "http://myjson.com/"
Paste your json code there. Then you will be provided a link by json ......then you can use this link in your project.

Answer (score 0):

JSON data is usually generated by a web application, but it is possible to put a file containing the JSON data on a server to be served by a normal web server.

Comment: how can i do this, did you have a link that explain this for a beginner with more details? Thanks

Comment: ... Are you really asking for a tutorial on how to put a file on the Internet?

Comment: i want to upload the json file on internet so i can read it. and if i want i change the json file with the url administrate.
I did it with image so i can see it from their url and change it with url administrate but i can not do it with json?
Do you have a site where i can download my json file and obtain an url of that json?

Comment: What leads you to believe that it's any different between a JSON file and, say, a PNG file?

Comment: when i try to download it, i got a message error: the file must be  format *.jpeg, *.gif ou *.png .

Comment: That would be an issue with the host, not the file. Contact support.